# Select Records for dates between Start Date/Time and End Date/Time

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column `TxDate` as a timestamp column. And I need to select the records from the table where `TxDate` falls between:

- the date range (`@StartDate` and `@EndDate`) and
- the time range (`@StartTime` and `@EndTime`).
  Here `@StartTime` is greater than `@EndTime`.

**Input:**

```sql
@StartDate = '2021-02-05'
@EndDate   = '2021-02-07'

@StartTime = '20:30:00'
@EndTime   = '03:30:00'
```

Here I need all the records from table where `TxDate` between input Date/Time

**Records in actual table :**

| TxDate | BDate | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-05 06:00:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-05 13:10:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-05 23:40:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 01:40:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 05:50:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 06:00:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 13:10:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 23:40:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-07 01:40:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-07 05:50:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-07 10:30:00.000 | 2021-02-07 | ABC |
| 2021-02-08 02:30:00.000 | 2021-02-07 | ABC |
| 2021-02-08 11:00:00.000 | 2021-02-08 | ABC |

**Required Output :**

| TxDate | BDate | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-05 23:40:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 01:40:00.000 | 2021-02-05 | ABC |
| 2021-02-06 23:40:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-07 01:40:00.000 | 2021-02-06 | ABC |
| 2021-02-08 02:30:00.000 | 2021-02-07 | ABC |

Comment: in your example u should be have a two record as result. its ok ?? the first two record

Comment: Does `StartTime` only relate to `StartDate` and `EndTime` only relates to `EndDate`, or does it mean that the time, whenever it is, must be between `StartTime` and `EndTime`? If the latter, how does that work, does that mean "either before 3:30 or after 20:30"?

Comment: I have updated the details for better understanding, let me know if you still have any question

Answer (score 0):

You can't split the datetime value into date and time you need separate columns for date and time to meet your conditions on it. and with that you can do like below:

```sql
SELECT * -- or the columns you need--
FROM theTable -- the name of the table--
WHERE 
     (StartDate <= @startdate)
AND 
     (EndDate >= @enddate)
AND 
     (StartTime <= @starttime)
AND
     (EndTime >= @endtime)
-- if your query is not about the exact StartDate and EndDates, just remove '=' --
```

Hope it helps. you but if doesn't feel free to give me more info to edit this for you

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting sometime like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM theTable
WHERE 
    TxDate BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate + @StartTime AS datetime) 
           AND CAST(@EndDate + @EndTime AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is datetime - you need to get all possible dates in the range, then filter out the times.  The problem is what to do with the edge cases - for example, for the start date of 2021-02-05 do you want to include the times between 00:00:00.000 and 03:30:00 and for the end date of 2021-02-07 do you want to include the times between 20:30:00 and 23:59:59?

I am going to assume you do not want to include those:

```
Declare @startDate date = '2021-02-05'
      , @endDate date = '2021-02-07'
      , @startTime time(0) = '20:30:00'
      , @endTime time(0) = '03:30:00';

Declare @startRange datetime = cast(@startDate As datetime) + cast(@startTime As datetime)
      , @endRange datetime = cast(@endDate As datetime) + cast(@endTime As datetime);

 Select TxDate
      , BDate
      , Item
   From dbo.YourTable
  Where TxDate >= @startRange
    And TxDate <= @endRange
    And cast(TxDate As time(0)) >= @startTime
    And cast(TxDate As time(0)) <= @endTime;
```

This is not tested - no sample data was provided.

Comment: When i say date 2021-02-05 and  times between 20:30:00 and 03:30:00. So the Start Date Time will be "2021-02-05 20:30:00" and End Date Time will be of next day and not for same day "2021-02-06 03:30:00".

Comment: Oops - since I couldn't test I had a bad copy/paste.  I edited my answer to calculate endRange using endDate and endTime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the `BDate` field would be helpful:

```
declare @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime,
        @startTime datetime, @endTime datetime
select  @startDate = '2021-02-05',  @endDate = '2021-02-07',
        @startTime = '20:30:00',    @endTime = '03:30:00'

select * from actualTable
where cast(BDate as datetime) between @startDate and @endDate
    and TxDate between cast(BDate as datetime) + @startTime
                and dateAdd(dd, 1, cast(BDate as datetime)) + @endTime
```